# Where would the stdout output by `~/.profile` have gone when starting Ubuntu?

Tags: startup, .profile

My `~/.profile` contains a command which outputs to stdout when Ubuntu 16.04 with LXDE is started.

I grep `/var/log/` for the output, but found nothing. Where would the output have gone, or is it lost forever?
Thanks.

See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/435189/674

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the login manager you use, `~/.profile` is not even executed when you login graphically, see https://superuser.com/questions/752493/profile-in-lxde#847051.

Also, in case it is executed (more technically correct "sourced"), the output to standard output will most likely be discarded.

If you want to write a log message, you could use the `logger` command (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man1/logger.1.html) to write to the system log, simply by piping your output into the logger command like this:

```
myCommand | logger
```

Answer (score 2):

`~/.profile` is a user specific script file (contrary to the scripts in the unix question you quoted). If you want to capture its output you have to redirect stdout and/or stderr to a file.

In /var/log you can see traces of events that are system relevant or concern all users.